# The fetched object at index X has an out of order section name 'X. Objects must be sorted by section name'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I know this has been covered in various questions, but I can't figure this one out.

As far as I can tell my setup is correct. My first sort descriptor matches the `sectionNameKeyPath` exactly.

My customers get this crash very rarely, perhaps because it isn't on a screen that is typically open for that long. Because the crash is rare, I haven't been able to reproduce it at all.

It crashes on viewWillAppear->table reloadData->numberOfSectionsInTableView->accessor for nsfetchedresultscontroller perform fetch.

It's always the same error message recorded to my crash reporter, with different numbers: 
**The fetched object at index 9 has an out of order section name '2. Objects must be sorted by section name'**

I use the statusId field, which is always a number of 1-5.

Code:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)unitsFetchedResultsController
{
    if (unitsFetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return unitsFetchedResultsController;
    }

    // SELECT * from Unit
    NSFetchRequest* fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Unit" inManagedObjectContext:self.guestCard.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    // make this more defensive by limiting the status ids (1-14ish are valid on the backend, we only display these) 
    NSPredicate *availablePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"available = 1"];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:availablePredicate];
    // ORDER BY ready DESC, availableDate ASC  (ATGT - must sort by 'ready' first or else 'sectionNameKeyPath' in the NSFetchedResultsController won't work)
    NSSortDescriptor* readySortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"statusId" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor* bedroomsSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"floorplan.bedrooms" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor* bathroomsSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"floorplan.baths" ascending:YES];
    NSSortDescriptor* availableDateSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"availableDate" ascending:YES];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:readySortDescriptor, bedroomsSortDescriptor, bathroomsSortDescriptor, availableDateSortDescriptor, nil]];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.guestCard.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"statusId" cacheName:@"unitsAvailable"];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.unitsFetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    // Clean up
    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![[self unitsFetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        [CoreDataErrorWriter writeCoreDataErrorToFile:error];

        perimeterAppDelegate *appDelegate = APP_DELEGATE;
        [appDelegate showCoreDataError];

        [NSException raise:@"Core Data Error" format:@"Core Data Error in %@", NSStringFromClass([self class])];
    }

    return self.unitsFetchedResultsController; // I recognize I should just return the iVar, but not the problem.
}
```

Comment: By any chance are you re-using that cache name elsewhere? Or is it possible you have a race condition involving updating the status ID from your server while the fetch request is executing? EDIT: Also, if your customers are somewhat consistently experiencing this issue, would it be worth destroying your fetched results controller and re-instantiating it instead of crashing the app?

Comment: It does pull from the server every 20 minutes or so, if there are any updates. I tested being on this screen when an update was pulled down for one of the units being displayed. That didn't cause an issue. Maybe it's only a problem if its being changed at the exact moment the performFetch occurs? It seems like that would be a lot more rare.